# How to pass an argument to a view?

Tags: views

I have a a view with Taxonomy terms on the front page.I want when I click on a taxonomy term,this taxonomy term to be passed to a second view as an argument to an exposed filter.The second view is on another page.How can I accomplish that?Is there any module for this?
Thanks in advance

SOLUTION
I finally found a solution.I have rewritten the ouput of the taxonomy term to something like that second_view/[tid] .So when I click on a taxonomy term I am redirected to the second view which is filtered by the tid.That's it!

Comment: What version of Drupal and views are you using?

Comment: You could answer your own question instead of editing the question text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another solution for that. Try to use the FacetAPI module: http://drupal.org/project/facetapi

Then you can create a view and integrate the taxonomy terms with the drupal search as explained in the following link:

http://envisioninteractive.com/drupal/drupal-7-views-with-faceted-filters-without-apachesolr/